# IF ELSE statement for datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the datetime difference in second. What my code does -> If the column `A.KIOSKLASTUPDATED` is NULL, get current time. Then calculate the time difference. This part is done correctly.

Now i want to add if else statement for the datetime difference in seconds. If the difference is <= 300 then do something else do something else

I am getting error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(B.OPERATORID, ' ', B.OPERATORNAME) 
     FROM ACTIVITY_LOG AS B 
     WHERE B.KIOSKID = A.KIOSKID 
     ORDER BY B.CREATED_AT DESC) AS CURRENTUSER,
    IF(DATEDIFF(ss, ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), A.KIOSKLASTUPDATED, 20), CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 20)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 20)) <= 300)
    BEGIN
        SELECT '1' AS KIOSKSTATUS
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT '0' AS KIOSKSTATUS
    END
FROM
    KIOSK_SETUP AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    DEPARTMENT AS C ON A.DEPARTMENTID = C.ID
```

Comment: why downvote my question? please explain so i know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(B.OPERATORID,' ',B.OPERATORNAME) FROM ACTIVITY_LOG AS B WHERE B.KIOSKID = A.KIOSKID ORDER BY B.CREATED_AT DESC
       ) AS CURRENTUSER,
       (CASE WHEN datediff(ss, ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), A.KIOSKLASTUPDATED, 20), CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), getdate(), 20)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), getdate(), 20)) <=300
             THEN '1' ELSE '0'
        END) AS KIOSKSTATUS
FROM KIOSK_SETUP A LEFT JOIN
     DEPARTMENT C 
     ON A.DEPARTMENTID = C.ID;
```

That said, you have  numerous other problems in the query:

- You are converting date/time values to *strings* and then using *datetime* functions on them.
- Your table aliases should be abbreviations for the table names.  `A` and `C` don't make sense.
- `IF()` is for T-SQL code, not for queries.